# npm install : unable to install dependencies in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I am using Windows 10 and installed node-v6.9.1-x64.

Here is the project [link](https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic) which I am trying to build for Android platform and for that I am following steps as mentioned there, like:

1. First of all I have downloaded this project and unzip to Ionic folder in D drive and renamed it to IonicUserBase
2. Second, I have already Ionic and Cordova installed, so I directly started with navigate to project
3. Third to install all dependencies, I am using : npm install

But unable to install dependecies .... see complete log below

```
D:\>cd Ionic

D:\Ionic>cd IonicUserBase

D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase>npm install
npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@0.3.13: Please use gulp-clean-css
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

> node-sass@0.9.6 install D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\node_modules\node-sass
> node build.js

(node:6292) DeprecationWarning: child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.

D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\node_modules\node-sass>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
[                 .] | install: info lifecycle node-sass@0.9.6~install: Failed to exec install script[                 .] | install: info lifecycle node-sass@0.9.6~instAuthenticate.me@1.0.0 D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase
+-- bower@1.7.9
+-- gulp@3.9.1
| +-- archy@1.0.0
| +-- chalk@1.1.3
| | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
| | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
| | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
| | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
| | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
| | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
| +-- deprecated@0.0.1
| +-- interpret@1.0.1
| +-- liftoff@2.3.0
| | +-- extend@3.0.0
| | +-- findup-sync@0.4.3
| | | +-- detect-file@0.1.0
| | | | `-- fs-exists-sync@0.1.0
| | | +-- is-glob@2.0.1
| | | | `-- is-extglob@1.0.0
| | | +-- micromatch@2.3.11
| | | | +-- arr-diff@2.0.0
| | | | | `-- arr-flatten@1.0.1
| | | | +-- array-unique@0.2.1
| | | | +-- braces@1.8.5
| | | | | +-- expand-range@1.8.2
| | | | | | `-- fill-range@2.2.3
| | | | | |   +-- is-number@2.1.0
| | | | | |   +-- isobject@2.1.0
| | | | | |   | `-- isarray@1.0.0
| | | | | |   +-- randomatic@1.1.5
| | | | | |   `-- repeat-string@1.6.1
| | | | | +-- preserve@0.2.0
| | | | | `-- repeat-element@1.1.2
| | | | +-- expand-brackets@0.1.5
| | | | | `-- is-posix-bracket@0.1.1
| | | | +-- extglob@0.3.2
| | | | +-- filename-regex@2.0.0
| | | | +-- kind-of@3.0.4
| | | | | `-- is-buffer@1.1.4
| | | | +-- normalize-path@2.0.1
| | | | +-- object.omit@2.0.1
| | | | | +-- for-own@0.1.4
| | | | | | `-- for-in@0.1.6
| | | | | `-- is-extendable@0.1.1
| | | | +-- parse-glob@3.0.4
| | | | | +-- glob-base@0.3.0
| | | | | | `-- glob-parent@2.0.0
| | | | | `-- is-dotfile@1.0.2
| | | | `-- regex-cache@0.4.3
| | | |   +-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3
| | | |   `-- is-primitive@2.0.0
| | | `-- resolve-dir@0.1.1
| | |   `-- global-modules@0.2.3
| | |     +-- global-prefix@0.1.4
| | |     | +-- ini@1.3.4
| | |     | +-- osenv@0.1.3
| | |     | | `-- os-tmpdir@1.0.2
| | |     | `-- which@1.2.11
| | |     |   `-- isexe@1.1.2
| | |     `-- is-windows@0.2.0
| | +-- fined@1.0.2
| | | +-- expand-tilde@1.2.2
| | | +-- lodash.assignwith@4.2.0
| | | +-- lodash.isempty@4.4.0
| | | +-- lodash.pick@4.4.0
| | | `-- parse-filepath@1.0.1
| | |   +-- is-absolute@0.2.6
| | |   | `-- is-relative@0.2.1
| | |   |   `-- is-unc-path@0.1.1
| | |   |     `-- unc-path-regex@0.1.2
| | |   +-- map-cache@0.2.2
| | |   `-- path-root@0.1.1
| | |     `-- path-root-regex@0.1.2
| | +-- flagged-respawn@0.3.2
| | +-- lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6
| | +-- lodash.isstring@4.0.1
| | +-- lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0
| | +-- rechoir@0.6.2
| | `-- resolve@1.1.7
| +-- minimist@1.2.0
| +-- orchestrator@0.3.7
| | +-- end-of-stream@0.1.5
| | | `-- once@1.3.3
| | |   `-- wrappy@1.0.2
| | +-- sequencify@0.0.7
| | `-- stream-consume@0.1.0
| +-- pretty-hrtime@1.0.2
| +-- semver@4.3.6
| +-- tildify@1.2.0
| | `-- os-homedir@1.0.2
| +-- v8flags@2.0.11
| | `-- user-home@1.1.1
| `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14
|   +-- defaults@1.0.3
|   | `-- clone@1.0.2
|   +-- glob-stream@3.1.18
|   | +-- glob@4.5.3
|   | | `-- inflight@1.0.6
|   | +-- glob2base@0.0.12
|   | | `-- find-index@0.1.1
|   | +-- minimatch@2.0.10
|   | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.6
|   | |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.2
|   | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
|   | +-- ordered-read-streams@0.1.0
|   | +-- through2@0.6.5
|   | | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
|   | `-- unique-stream@1.0.0
|   +-- glob-watcher@0.0.6
|   | `-- gaze@0.5.2
|   |   `-- globule@0.1.0
|   |     +-- glob@3.1.21
|   |     | +-- graceful-fs@1.2.3
|   |     | `-- inherits@1.0.2
|   |     +-- lodash@1.0.2
|   |     `-- minimatch@0.2.14
|   |       +-- lru-cache@2.7.3
|   |       `-- sigmund@1.0.1
|   +-- graceful-fs@3.0.11
|   | `-- natives@1.1.0
|   +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
|   | `-- minimist@0.0.8
|   +-- strip-bom@1.0.0
|   | +-- first-chunk-stream@1.0.0
|   | `-- is-utf8@0.2.1
|   +-- through2@0.6.5
|   | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
|   `-- vinyl@0.4.6
|     `-- clone@0.2.0
+-- gulp-concat@2.6.0
| +-- concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.4
| | `-- source-map@0.5.6
| `-- through2@0.6.5
|   +-- readable-stream@1.0.34
|   | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
|   | +-- inherits@2.0.3
|   | +-- isarray@0.0.1
|   | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31
|   `-- xtend@4.0.1
+-- gulp-minify-css@0.3.13
| +-- bufferstreams@0.0.2
| | `-- readable-stream@1.1.14
| +-- clean-css@3.0.10
| | +-- commander@2.5.1
| | `-- source-map@0.1.43
| |   `-- amdefine@1.0.0
| +-- memory-cache@0.0.5
| +-- through2@0.6.5
| | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
| `-- vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4
|   `-- source-map@0.1.43
+-- gulp-rename@1.2.2
+-- gulp-util@2.2.20
| +-- chalk@0.5.1
| | +-- ansi-styles@1.1.0
| | +-- has-ansi@0.1.0
| | | `-- ansi-regex@0.2.1
| | +-- strip-ansi@0.3.0
| | `-- supports-color@0.2.0
| +-- dateformat@1.0.12
| | +-- get-stdin@4.0.1
| | `-- meow@3.7.0
| |   +-- camelcase-keys@2.1.0
| |   | `-- camelcase@2.1.1
| |   +-- decamelize@1.2.0
| |   +-- loud-rejection@1.6.0
| |   | +-- currently-unhandled@0.4.1
| |   | | `-- array-find-index@1.0.2
| |   | `-- signal-exit@3.0.1
| |   +-- map-obj@1.0.1
| |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5
| |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.5
| |   | +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0
| |   | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
| |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
| |   |   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2
| |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.2
| |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4
| |   +-- object-assign@4.1.0
| |   +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
| |   | +-- find-up@1.1.2
| |   | | +-- path-exists@2.1.0
| |   | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
| |   | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
| |   | `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
| |   |   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0
| |   |   | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.9
| |   |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0
| |   |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.0
| |   |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1
| |   |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
| |   |   | `-- strip-bom@2.0.0
| |   |   `-- path-type@1.1.0
| |   +-- redent@1.0.0
| |   | +-- indent-string@2.1.0
| |   | | `-- repeating@2.0.1
| |   | |   `-- is-finite@1.0.2
| |   | |     `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1
| |   | `-- strip-indent@1.0.1
| |   `-- trim-newlines@1.0.0
| +-- lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1
| +-- lodash.template@2.4.1
| | +-- lodash._escapestringchar@2.4.1
| | +-- lodash.defaults@2.4.1
| | | `-- lodash._objecttypes@2.4.1
| | +-- lodash.escape@2.4.1
| | | +-- lodash._escapehtmlchar@2.4.1
| | | | `-- lodash._htmlescapes@2.4.1
| | | `-- lodash._reunescapedhtml@2.4.1
| | +-- lodash.keys@2.4.1
| | | +-- lodash._isnative@2.4.1
| | | +-- lodash._shimkeys@2.4.1
| | | `-- lodash.isobject@2.4.1
| | +-- lodash.templatesettings@2.4.1
| | `-- lodash.values@2.4.1
| +-- minimist@0.2.0
| +-- multipipe@0.1.2
| | `-- duplexer2@0.0.2
| +-- through2@0.5.1
| | +-- readable-stream@1.0.34
| | `-- xtend@3.0.0
| `-- vinyl@0.2.3
|   `-- clone-stats@0.0.1
`-- shelljs@0.3.0

npm WARN Authenticate.me@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN Authenticate.me@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@0.9.6 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\npm-debug.log

D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase>
```

**UPDATED:**

I have tried the way suggested by @mscdex and here is the new [log](http://pastebin.com/5z60fRTZ), still getting build failed while using `npm install` and one more thing now I have installed another version of nodejs (i.e. node-v4.2.1-x64)

Comment: The actual errors should come *before* the *console* output you've posted from your new logs, so you will need to post that as well.

Comment: @mscdex hey friend sorry for late response, please check this one: http://pastebin.com/5z60fRTZ and one more thing now I uninstalled last version and installed new version of node js (i.e. node-v4.2.1-x64)

Comment: Did you have admin permissions when you try to install packages?

Comment: try to install single module instead of dependency which show bunch of error like npm install express

Comment: Yeah, install dependencies one by one to find which dependency is causing error or whether if npm is causing the problem

Answer (score 6):

I cloned the [project](https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic) and tried the same.

By adding PythonPath to the Windows environment and updating the gulp-sass to it's latest version I am able to build the project successfully

***Step 1:***

Download Python 2.7.12 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/python-2.7.12.msi)

And set the environment variable PATH to /path/to/executable/python2.7 (eg: C:\Python27\python.exe)

OR

open cmd as administrator and run

```
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

I have done both.

***Step 2:***

Open your package.json (D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase\package.json)

change the version of [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)  from `"gulp-sass": "^0.7.1"` to it's latest version `"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"`

now try  `npm install`

It should work fine.

***Summary:***
Let me summarize the entire flow

Open cmd as *admin*

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools from cmd as administrator
git clone https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic.git
cd Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic
```

In package.json change the version of gulp-sass to it's latest version. "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"

```
npm install
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

Answer (score 2):

`node-sass` is a node addon, so it needs to be compiled. However, you don't have at least Python installed to be able to compile addons.

On Windows, you *should* be able to install everything you need by just doing this (either from an elevated PowerShell session or from a command prompt ran as Administrator):

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Once that successfully completes, re-run your original `npm install`.

**EDIT:** After reading your `npm install` log, it appears that you are depending on an old version of `gulp-sass` since a really old version of `node-sass` is being installed (`node-sass` v0.9.6 was released in 2014). Try installing and using the latest version of `gulp-sass` (v2.3.2 as of this writing) instead, which should bring in a much more recent `node-sass` that is compatible with modern versions of node.

Comment: please check above I have tried your way, but still getting build failed while using npm install....

Comment: hey I have tried this way as well, but I did not get any success, even getting same issue, see command and new log here: http://pastebin.com/jixGgRRH

Comment: You're getting the same issue because you're running the same `npm install` from the same directory (D:\Ionic\IonicUserBase) that has a package.json with a reference to an older `gulp-sass` dependency still.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar version i solved by installing python 2.7

```
npm install --python=python2.7
```

or set it to be used always:

```
npm config set python python2.7
```

Also i had visual stdio 2015 and 2012 installed.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `npm rebuild node-sass`?

If that doesn't work, then you likely need to go into your `package.json` and update your dependencies. When I get messy node errors I usually do something like this:

Delete your `node_modules` folder and back up your `package.json`. Then remove all the dependencies from your `package.json` and install each one manually using `npm install package_name --save`. This will install the latest version of each package - and it will likely fix your problem. I have experienced inconsistencies with `npm update` which is why I recommend this manual process.